# Does influence graph have multiple directed edges?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, directed-graphs

so I am studying about graphs from the book discrete maths by Keneth Rosen 7th edition.Pg:645
However, I am bit unsatisifed with one of the statements from the book. So I would like to get it reviewed from someone who knows.
[image: Text about influence graph from the book]

[image: Figure7 associated with the text]

**Here the textbook says that in figure 7 there is no multiple directed edges. However I can clearly see there is multiple directed edges between Brian and Yvonne. Is the textbook getting wrong here or I seriously need to look back my concepts? Please help me.**

Answer (score 0):

"Multiple edges", in this context, has a technical meaning. (Used informally, it's obviously nonsense, because of course the graph has more than one edge.) It means that edges cannot have multiplicity: the *same* edge cannot appear multiple times.

It is okay to have the edge $(\text{Brian}, \text{Yvonne})$ as well as the edge $(\text{Yvonne}, \text{Brian})$, because these are different directed edges. However, in this context, it would be meaningless to have two copies of the edge $(\text{Brian}, \text{Yvonne})$: what would it mean, to have Brian "influence Yvonne twice"?

I would not say that an influence graph is a widely-recognized term, so you don't have to worry about its definition in other contexts. However, the term **simple directed graph** is commonly used for graphs that don't have loops (edges of the form $(u,u)$) or multiple edges (multiple copies of the same edge $(u,v)$). Some sources will also just call this a **directed graph** and assume by default that it is simple, and say **directed multigraph** to allow loops and multiple edges.

It is also possible to make other sets of assumptions:

- A **loopless directed (multi)graph** forbid loops, but allows multiple copies of the same edge.
- An **oriented graph** (this is a less common term, but still often used) is even more restrictive, and forbids the thing that happens in the question: at most one of the edges $(u,v)$ or $(v,u)$ can exist. These directed graphs are called "oriented graphs" because they are exactly the class of graphs that can be obtained from undirected graphs by giving each edge an orientation.